# Preppend a new child div ahead of previous child div's jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to a do a simple media posting project. When new records are added to the database I use ajax to add a new child div to a parent div based on the info in the record. I have it working except for the order that children are added in. Doing a prepend does not place the new div as the first child of the parent div, it puts it as the last child of the specified parent. That's no good when I want new posts displayed on top. Here is the code for the file I'm working on. How do I prepend above previously added children?

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    setInterval(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: 'JSONFile.php',
           data: { get_param: 'value' }, 
           dataType: 'json',
           success: function(retrieved){
               //$("#MainContent").empty();
               $.each(retrieved, function(index, i){
                   $('#MainContent').append('<br><div class="Post"><h2>' + i.UserName + '</h2><br><p>' + i.Content + '</p></div>');
               });
           }
       });
    },3000);   
});
```

Comment: "*Doing a prepend does not place the new div as the first child of the parent div, it puts it as the last child of the specified parent.*" - that seems unlikely, given the use-case of [`prepend()`](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) (not to mention the name of the method). Can you show the code in which `prepend()` does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.append`, you can use [`.prepend`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/), which was made for exactly this purpose:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the beginning of each element in the set of matched elements.

So, you can use the code:

```
$.each(retrieved, function(index, i){
  $('#MainContent').prepend('<br><div class="Post"><h2>' + i.UserName + '</h2><br><p>' + i.Content + '</p></div>');
});
```

Comment: Or there's [`before()`](https://api.jquery.com/before/), in the event that the already-present element is not the first child (in which case `prepend()` would be the most sensible method).

Comment: Ah perfect. Thank You!

Comment: Im told i cant accept an answer after only seven minnutes, so Ill come back and mark your answer as the right one once stack overflow lets me in a few minutes. Appreciate your time!